# how do I find interface name when the card is in monitor mode?

Tags: bash, shell

Hi im using `iface=$(route | grep '^default' | grep -o '[^ ]*$')` do find the name of the interface currently being used and then assigning the name to the variable `$iface`. This doesnt work in monitor mode though. I'm wondering if anyone has a way to find the name of the interface when its in monitor mode.

The goal is for $iface to be assigned only the name of the interface i.e. `wlan0` or for monitor mode `wlan0mon`